# Optimizing a SQL Query with Complex Filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

Please note that the question below is specifically for **MySQL**.

Imagine a table called `Cars` with the following structure (*we can ignore the lack of proper key constraints, etc. as it is not relevant to my question*):

```
CREATE TABLE Cars
(
  id Integer,
  maker_id Integer,
  status_id Integer,
  notes Varchar(100)
);
```

Now imagine loading some test data like this:

```
INSERT INTO Cars
(id, maker_id, status_id, notes)
VALUES
(1, 1001, 0, 'test1'),
(2, 1001, 0, 'test2'),
(3, 1001, 0, 'test3'),
(4, 1002, 0, 'test4'),
(5, 1002, 0, 'test5'),
(6, 1002, 1, 'test6'),
(7, 1002, 1, 'test7'),
(8, 1002, 2, 'test8'),
(9, 1003, 3, 'test9'),
(10, 1003, 3, 'test10'),
(11, 1003, 4, 'test11'),
(12, 1003, 4, 'test12'),
(13, 1003, 5, 'test13'),
(14, 1003, 5, 'test14')
```

There are 14 records, with 3 `DISTINCT` values in `maker_id` (1001, 1002, 1003), and 6 `DISTINCT` values in `status_id` (0,1,2,3,4,5).

Now, imagine taking the `DISTINCT` pairs of (`maker_id`, `status_id`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker_id, status_id FROM Cars;
```

Here is a link to an example in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1c7/2

This results in the following records (`maker_id`, `status_id`):

- (1001, 0)
- (1002, 0)
- (1002, 1)
- (1002, 2)
- (1003, 3)
- (1003, 4)
- (1003, 5)

The logic for what I need to return is as follows:

If a given `maker_id` value (e.g., 1001) only has 1 distinct record for its corresponding `DISTINCT` (`maker_id`, `status_id`) pairs, simply return it. In this example: (1001, 0).

If a given `maker_id` value has *more than 1* distinct record for its corresponding `DISTINCT` (`maker_id`, `status_id`) pairs, return all of them *except* the one with a `status_id` value of 0. In this example: (1002, 1), (1002, 2), (1003, 3), (1003, 4), and (1003, 5).

Notice that we left out (1002, 0).

Can anybody think of a conciser / more efficient (in terms of runtime) way of writing this query? In the real world, my table has millions of records.

I have come up with the following:

```
SELECT
  subq.maker_id,
  subq.status_id
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    maker_id,
    status_id,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cars WHERE maker_id = c.maker_id AND status_id != 0 GROUP BY maker_id) AS counter
  FROM Cars AS c
) AS subq

WHERE
  subq.counter IS NULL
  OR (subq.counter IS NOT NULL AND subq.status_id != 0)
;
```

Here is an example in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb1c7/3

Comment: 1. What index do you have? 2. Subselect the two cases separately first.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for the response! 1) We don't have indeces (and can't create them) 2) Do you mean do two subselects and UNION the results?

Comment: Two selects and UNION is the only other way I can think of right now...

Comment: Yes. This avoids grouping.

Comment: @cuddlyhugbear: the absence of indexes on a huge table is a flashing yellow warning light, and the inability to create an index is a blaring klaxon horn. That's a ship I don't want to be on board, because there is something seriously wrong with that ship. In the real world, tables with millions of rows have indexes. For performance, `UNION ALL` beats `UNION`, because it avoids the overhead of a sort unique operation to remove duplicates.

Comment: With no indexes on the table, we can't even hold out hope that Obi-Wan Kenobi can help us with performance. The Dark Side has won. There's no getting around either a sort of a huge set or multiple passes through a huge table.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- very much appreciated! Absolutely right with respect to the indexes (indices?). I have recommended that this happen, but I don't have control over it myself, so fingers crossed that the voice of reason wins out!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `id` isn't a `PRIMARY KEY`, and there aren't implicit indices from the supposed `FOREIGN KEY`s `maker_id` and `status_id`?

Comment: @Arth,,,which is something we'd see from the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Cars`.

Comment: @spencer7593 I agree, but there is no evidence that the `CREATE TABLE` statement shown is the one revealed by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. As OP is asking for efficiency, I wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several query patterns that can return the specified result. Some are going to look more complicated than others. There's likely to be *big* differences in performance.

Performing a `GROUP BY` operation on a huge set can be costly (in terms of resources and elapsed time ESPECIALLY if MySQL can't make use of an index to optimize that operation. (Using a `GROUP BY` operation is one way to get a count of `status_id` for each `maker_id`.)

And correlated subqueries can be expensive, when they are executed repeatedly. I usually only see better performance out of correlated subqueries when the number of times they need to be executed is limited.

I think the best shot at getting good performance would be something like this:

**NOT TESTED**

```
 SELECT c.maker_id
      , c.status_id
   FROM Cars c
  WHERE c.status_id > 0

 UNION ALL

 SELECT d.maker_id
      , d.status_id
   FROM Cars d
   LEFT
   JOIN Cars e
     ON e.maker_id = d.maker_id
    AND e.status_id > 0
  WHERE e.maker_id IS NULL  
    AND d.status_id = 0
```

As to whether that's more efficient or more concise than other query approaches, we'd need to test.

But for any shot at good performance with this query, we are going to need an index.

```
..  ON Cars (maker_id, status_id)
```

We expect the EXPLAIN output will show "Using index" in the `Extra` column. And we're not expecting a "Using filesort".

One big downside of this approach is that's effectively going to be two passes through the table (or index).

The first SELECT is pretty straightforward... get me all the rows where `status_id` is not zero. We need all those rows. It's possible that an index e.g.

```
... ON Cars (status_id, maker_id)
```

might be of benefit for that query. But if we're returning a significant portion of the table, I'd bet dollars to donuts that a full scan of the other index will be just as fast, or faster.

The second `SELECT` uses an *anti-join* pattern. What this is doing is getting all rows that have a `status_id` equal to zero, and from that set, "filtering out" any of the rows where there's another row, for the same `maker_id` with a `status_id` other than zero.

We do the filtering with an outer join operation (`LEFT JOIN`) to return all rows with `status_id=0`, along with any and all matching rows. The *trick* is the predicate in the `WHERE` clause that filters out all the rows that had a match. So what we're left with is rows that didn't find a match. That is, values of `maker_id` which have *only* a `status_id=0` row.

We could get an equivalent result using a `NOT EXISTS` predicate rather than an *anti-join*. But in my experience, sometimes the performance is not as good. We could re-write that second `SELECT` (following the `UNION ALL` operation)

```
 SELECT d.maker_id
      , d.status_id
   FROM Cars d
  WHERE d.status_id = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM Cars e
           WHERE e.maker_id = d.maker_id
             AND e.status_id > 0
        )
```

And performance of that query is going to be dependent on a suitable index just like the anti-join is.

IMPORTANT: Do *not* omit the `ALL` keyword. A `UNION ALL` operation just concatenates the results of the two queries. If we omit the `ALL` keyword, then we are requiring that MySQL to perform a "sort unique" operation to eliminate duplicate rows.

NOTE: The reason for the `UNION ALL` rather than an `OR` condition is that I've usually gotten much better query plans with the `UNION ALL`. The MySQL optimizer doesn't seem to do too well with `OR` when the predicates are on different columns and conditions, and either predicate can be used to "drive" the execution plan. With the `UNION ALL`, breaking it into two queries, we can usually get a good plan for both parts.

Comment: What a tremendously thoughtful post; thank you! You're right, there is definitely a performance increase with the UNION ALL approach. Working through the details of the query now on my actual (large) data set.

Comment: @cuddlyhugbear: I added another possible approach in another answer. If there are *no* indexes on the table, and it's *impossible* to create an index (for whatever reason), it's possible the query in my other answer might be faster.

Comment: hang on, where is the `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in this answer?

Comment: @cuddlyhugbear: I entirely missed the specification about removing *duplicate* tuples. The quick fix for this query would be to remove the **`ALL`** keyword, replace `UNION ALL` with just `UNION`, and voila, we got ourselves a sort unique operation.

Comment: Very neat! Although pedantically you're probably still slightly better off throwing a couple of `DISTINCT`s in and keeping the `UNION ALL`.. that way each query only needs to look for dupes in it's own set.

Comment: Or, add a `GROUP BY` clause, or the `DISTINCT` keyword to each `SELECT`.  (Again @Arth, your are absolutely right. If OP wants the entire set sorted, then add an ORDER BY to the entire query.)

Comment: Thanks again -- really helpful guidance. I am actually curious if DISTINCT + UNION ALL beats out A simple UNION. Will try to run it when I have time and post back here :)

Comment: cuddlyhugbear: You're right. You'd need to test. In theory, the "unique sort" operations on two smaller sets is potentially faster than a "unique sort" of the whole set. (The difference is duplicates between the sets, which isn't a concern in this particular case since we are guaranteed the two sets are distinct. One set has only `status_id=0` rows, the other doesn't have any of those rows. But if you needed a sort to get the whole set in order by `maker_id` then just sorting the total set might be faster. "In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is."

Answer (score 1):

this query will help :)

```
select
    distinct c1.maker_id, c1.status_id
from
    Cars AS c1
where
    c1.status_id!=0
    or c1.maker_id not in (
        select distinct c2.maker_id
        from Cars AS c2
        where c2.status_id!=0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

As an entirely different approach to my first answer...

Given an impossible situation... no indexes on the table, and no possibility of creating an index... we're essentially left with two really bad choices: a sort of a huge set and a couple of passes through it, or a huge number of passes through a huge table.

The lesser of the two evils seems to be the sort. We can't afford an index, but we can afford the cycles to build an index on the fly in our query. And a bloatload of disk io to /tmp. There's a heatsink installed on the SSD, right?

We'll just sort the whole flipping set, and run through it a couple of times.

```
  SELECT t.maker_id
       , t.status_id
    FROM ( SELECT IF(s.status_id=0 AND s.maker_id=@p_maker,NULL,s.status_id) AS status_id
                , @p_maker := s.maker_id AS maker_id
             FROM ( SELECT @p_maker := NULL ) i
            CROSS
             JOIN ( SELECT c.maker_id
                         , c.status_id
                      FROM Cars c
                     GROUP BY c.maker_id DESC, c.status_id DESC 
                     ORDER BY c.maker_id DESC, c.status_id DESC
                  ) s
         ) t
   WHERE t.status_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about performance.. but I like the elegance of:

```
  SELECT maker_id,
         status_id
    FROM cars  
   WHERE status_id != 0
GROUP BY maker_id, status_id
   UNION ALL
  SELECT maker_id,
         MAX(status_id) max_status_id
    FROM cars  
GROUP BY maker_id
  HAVING max_status_id = 0
```

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks, but the dupes are right there in the sample data and distinct records are specifically mentioned and subsequently requested in the requirements.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I entirely missed the elimination of the duplicate tuples.  A very clever approach. I like it.